# NSMutableArray: How add a sorting value (int) to array's objects AFTER sorting it?

Tags: ios, loops, nsarray

Got a tableView with some player objects in it, sorted ASC by best playerTime after each game try a player makes.

Now I want to add a value (int) that shows the players placement in the playerlist (tableview), that will be reflected on the the players custom cell in the tableView. Got the custom cell working already with the dynamic data, just I need the "placement" int.

How do I handle the array to do this? Must be done after the list (NSArray) been sorted by best playerTime.

- I guess, some kind of iteration step one and two maybe (like an if-then statement)?
- Maybe there is a smart NSArray property for this specific need?

Any tips or suggestions? Thank's.

Comment: value (int)  that shows the players placement on what bases

Comment: As u haven't shared any code so what I can suggest you is to look for `NSSortDescriptor` This may help you.

Comment: So what you're after to is to get each cell to display its position on the table, correct (1st cell shows top player, so his position is '1')?

Comment: Sorry if I was short in my description and no code. But it's just as Alladinian said: 1st cell will show position 1, cell 2 position 2 etc. But to get this int, I need to somehow first sort the array first (to see which player got which position) and then insert an "position" int into every object and then present the updated objects with the current position int, in array in the tableview. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just display the row's value into your custom cell's label:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //...
    myCustomCell.positionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", (indexPath.row + 1)];
    //...
}
```

Now if you have a player object and want to retrieve its position in your sorted array, you just do this:

```
int playerPosition = [mySortedArray indexOfObject:playerObject] + 1;
```

Comment: Thank's Alladinian, that was a great and simple way to do it I think. Will give it a try later today (and then check correct answer to).

Comment: Update: I just added; `cell.cellPlayerStarIcon.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", (indexPath.row +1)];` to method cellForrowAtIndexPath and it worked like a sharm. Thank's again for prompt response!